# Is table lock using Copy table to other table in mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, copy

I want to copy my table to another same table in mysql phpmyadmin.

I have around 7,00,00,000+ records in table. I want to us operations facility "**Copy table to**".

I want to know that during this copy, is my parent table lock for Insert operations or not.

Comment: why you are not using simple select insert query at command line terminal. you can use following command INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;

Comment: @Lawakush Kurmi Is this process lock table or not, and do you idea about time to completion?

Comment: Please read this article i am sure you will get valuable help from it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html